# Column comparison (upper)

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I'm pretty new with Symfony and I would like to know how to proceed to compare a column with a string.

I'm using the QueryBuilder in a repository.
The equivalent WHERE clause in MySQL is :

```sql
WHERE UPPER(a.name) = UPPER(my_app_var)
```

```php
class ApplicationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function existsByName($name, $caseSensitive = false)
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

        if ($caseSensitive)
        {
            $builder->where($builder->expr()->eq('a.name', $name));
        }
        else
        { 
            $builder->where($builder->expr()->eq('a.name', $builder->expr()->upper($name)));
        }

        return count($builder->getQuery()->getResult()) != 0; 
    }
}
```

Symfony returns me a syntax error :

> QueryException: `SELECT a FROM Application a WHERE a.name = UPPER(my_var_app)`

Comment: Does the exception tell anything else? This query, by itself, seems valid...

Comment: Thanks. No other strange thing, I have also this message : `QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 81: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'my_var_app' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encase your final variable in ''  (single quotes) for the upper call.  You will also need "" (double quotes) for variable interpolation

```
   $builder->where($builder->expr()
                   ->eq('a.name'
                        ,$builder->expr()
                         ->upper("'$name'")));   //// here
```